# Accessing the xml using xpath

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am getting xpath from database as character. I want to retrieve that element from XML using esql. Since the xpath is character , I am not able to retrieve the element from XML. Is any way to convert the character to refer the XML? 
For example, my xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<catalog> 
<book id="bk101"> 
<author>Gambardella, Matthew</author> 
<title>XML Developer's Guide</title> 
<price>44.95</price> 
<publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date> 
</book> 
<diary> 
<abc>sample</abc> 
</diary> 
</catalog>
```

and I get the path catalog.book from database as character. I want to retrieve element book for further processing. But since catalog.book is character, I am not able to retrieve the element. Please suggest a method for doing this in esql.

Comment: You really need to identify which ESQL you are asking about.  There's [tag:embedded-sql] (which needs the DBMS specified and you should at least mention the host language), [tag:entity-sql] for Microsoft systems using Entity Framework, etc, and [tag:extended-sql] for IBM systems (WebSphere Message Broker, MQ, IBM Integration Bus).  I suspect you're referring to one of the latter two, but I can't identify which.  (OTOH, from a pragmatic viewpoint, I'm happy to have this question left with just the [tag:esql] tag so that the tag survives and points users to the correct alternatives.)

Answer (score 0):

You can access field by referencing to path stored in variable if you put variable name into {} brackets.

Like this:

```
DECLARE fieldPath CHARACTER;
SET fieldPath = ........ ;
SET Environment.Variables.Book = InputRoot.MRM.{fieldPath};
```